# Run Java application as a different user login

Tags: java, perl, uac

I need to run a few `perl` scripts from a Java GUI application. I am using `Runtime` API to do that. However, few of the perl scripts need to run under a specific user account to have special credentials to access specialized resources (e.g. Database, Files). I have heard of alleviating user access using `UAC`. But till now I am not able to find the solution. Please help me on how to run a process under a different user login. Is there anything similar to `c#` `impersonization` in Java?

Comment: On which operating system do you want to do this?

Comment: It's in Windows XP and Windows Server 2008. Probably, in future any windows platform.

Comment: Is this even possible? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Java, being a multi-platform language, tends not to have any platform specific things built in, therefore the Java platform has no concept of Windows' UAC.

Because of this, and your intention of only ever using Windows, I would question why you're using Java at all... None of the classes in `java.lang` such as `ProcessBuilder` seem to have any option of specifying a username/password.

What you could do is call Windows' `runas.exe` with some parameters:

```
runas.exe /noprofile /env /user:DOMAIN\username perl.exe myscript.pl
```

You would get a command prompt asking you for a password though

Comment: When I use this command, its asking for the password. Once I provide the password it says Attempting to start _application_ as _user_. But the application is not started.